# Make a delete button invisible using attrs. I am using Odoo 10

Tags: odoo-10

I need to make a delete button invisible using `attrs`.

my code here.
    in this code i want to put invisible delete button.

```xml
<record id="calender_event_form_id1" model="ir.ui.view">
          <field name="name">calender_event</field>
            <field name="model">calendar.event</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="calendar.view_calendar_event_form_popup"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml" delete="false">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_ids']" position="after">
                    <field name="c_is_meeting_done" string="Is Meeting Done?" readonly="1"/>
                    <field name="description"/>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='alarm_ids']" position="after">
                    <div name="buttons">
                        <button name="%(ouc_meeting_wizard_action)d" string="Close Meeting" attrs="{'invisible':[('c_is_meeting_done', '=', True)]}" type="action" class="oe_highlight" />
                    </div>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Comment: Could you post python code also?

Answer (score 0):

You can give "**delete=1**" to your particular view from xml. Like this:

```
<form string="Custom" delete="1"/>
```